# Oracle ADF : Tabbed pane

Tags: oracle, tabs, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We have developed web application using Oracle ADF. In our application we have a page with tabbedPane as show below.

[image: Tabbed Pane Containing 3 tabs]

In the above picture we have a tabbed pane that contains 3 tabs. Each tab contains a table. For every table row we have to execute one sql query.

Our problem is when we switch from purchase tab to inventory tab, queries of both the tabs getting execute. So, Its taking too much time. Can we restrict our tabbed pane so that only one tab table should get generated. Means if I click purchase tab only purchase tab table should get generated and if I click Inventory then only Inventory table should get generate not both the purchase and Inventory tab's tables.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you set  `childCreation="lazy"` on `af:panelTabbed`, you will get this behaviour:

1. On first accessing the page, only Purchase view object will be queried.
2. If you move to Inventory, the underlying view object is going to be re-queried.
3. If you open Sales, sales data will be queried.

Comment: Hello marcus. I changed the settings as you guided. But still the same problem. Both the time queries are executed. Can I know which tab user has clicked?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, it seems. If you will write a sample application running on HR schema, you will have the same behaviour as I described earlier.  I do presume you are using business components - do you have "CacheResults=true" on the page binding's  iterators?

Comment: Yes marcus. I have "CacheResults=true" on the page binding's iterators.

Comment: Do you use af:table component to show the contents of 'Purchase' table? Is it based on data controls, i.e.: simply drag and drop the iterator into the page? Or is it coming from an af:region?

Comment: Yes am using af:table component to show the contents of 'Purchase' table. Yes it is based on data control. To the existing table(created by drag and drop from data control) I have manually added some columns to the table. It is not coming from af:region.

Comment: My code is as follows <af:table value="#{bindings.BusinessHlthFinAp1.collectionModel}" var="row"
                      rows="#{bindings.BusinessHlthFinAp1.rangeSize}"
                      emptyText="#{bindings.BusinessHlthFinAp1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                      fetchSize="#{bindings.BusinessHlthFinAp1.rangeSize}" rowBandingInterval="0" id="bfApTbl"
                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_business_FH_TF_FirstPage.bfApTbl}"
                      columnStretching="column:kpiNAp" styleClass="AFStretchWidth">

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. In cases like this I usually re-create the same UI on a sample application using HR schema, and  observe the behaviour there. If the sample application works 'as expected', I start comparing the real application with the sample one. In most of the cases I am able to notice a minor difference - a flag missing - that fixes my problem.

What you should be sure of is that your current application doesn't work according ADF specifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SampledisclosureEvent(DisclosureEvent disclosureEvent) {
        if (disclosureEvent.isExpanded()== true) {

    // Your code here...    

        }
    }
```

if you have used disclosurelistener then in your disclosure method try using this
code. it will only enter the if values are true.

hope you get your solution.

update with what answer you get.